# Power MOSFETs IRFP260N and IRFP90N20D

Tags: mosfet

[image]I have been testing some MOSFETs like the IRFP260N. In the data sheet, it shows 200 V. What does the 200 V mean? I slowly added more power from 24 VDC up to 27 VDC and the FET shorted.

I have another amplifier I am building but using a IRFP90N20D. The datasheet shows 600 V.  What is the maximum voltage I can power this FET with? If the 260 is good for 24 V then the 90N20D should be good for 30 to 40 V or more to get the rated 550 W power dissipation.

I guess I don't understand why the datasheet shows a voltage that the FET can't handle because at 25.5 VDC I'm getting 300 W out of the IRFP260N, the rated power, so the IRFP90N20D has a higher voltage but not sure what to run it at because I'm pretty sure it's not 600 V.

Comment: Please put a drawing of your circuit in the question.  A schematic diagram, not a wiring diagram.

Comment: "The datasheet shows 200V" -- 200V what? Ratings are always given with a description and symbol. Look up what those symbols/descriptions mean.

Comment: So I googled the datasheet. IRFP260NPbF Power MOSFET - Infineon
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFP260N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535628a2ef1fe4. The datasheet says Vdss is 200V. You remind me that some two years ago I started seriously learning MOSFET, by reading a free eBook. It took me some 200+ hours reading thoroughly a couple of chapters, before I appreciated the Vdss thing.

Comment: Yes the vdss shows 200v but that's not the actual power this fet can handle I also add a schematic similar to what I'm making

Comment: It seems like you are having some misconceptions what the datasheet parameters mean. You could read up in it e.g. here https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/809.php

Comment: Have you considered that the cause of shorted MOSfet *might not* be drain overvoltage? Keep an open mind when troubleshooting.

Comment: "should be good for 30 to 40 V or more to get the rated 550 W power dissipation" the power dissipation spec is the amount of power the MOSFET can itself dissipate as heat, not the amount of power you can get or if a circuit which uses the MOSFET.

Comment: I have the gate voltage at 1.2vdc and drain voltage at 25.5vdc and getting 300watts but if I increase the drain voltage I may get more power out I did try this one and got to about 27v and my psu shut down  I check the fets with a mega 328 to match gates voltage and capacitance  this is a linear amplifier for HF ham radio  with a easy to find fet vs say 2sc2879 that are getting hard to come by nowadays

Comment: The way it's set up now the fets are mounted to a large  heatsink I can talk for 5 minutes pushing 250watts maybe 300 on a loud voice peaks and the fets or the heatsink not even warm I do have small case fan blowing on the input binocular toroid and fets  now I'm not using any feed back resistors in this and set the bias voltage to 1.2 to 1.5  now this is used in sideband   I guess I just need to know what a good voltage that I could run the IRFP90N20D

Answer (score 7):

I think the MOSFETs don't die by overvoltage here. We can expect twice the supply voltage at the drain, which would be 96V if you go up to 48V input. So there is plenty of room left for some ringing until it becomes dangeous for the FETs.

They are just too slow to follow your input frequency. One is not fully off while the other starts conducting or never turns on enough. You can see this in the large difference in the output power between 40m band and 20m band. IRFP90N20D is much slower than IRFP260N and I expect that it will not perform better here.

In the 20m band (=15MHz) one period is around 66ns, so in an ideal circuit  one FET is conducting for 33ns and off for 33ns. When you select a MOSFET, look at the rise and fall times. They should not be far away from this timing.

Whe you increase the supply voltage but the FET cannot rise the current faster, all the additional voltage is across the FET (heat) and not across the tank coil (output power).

I think some faster FETs like e.g. PHP33NQ20T or IXFY36N20X3 with a bit lower DC power parameters but half the rise time, are worth a test here for comparison, especially in the 20m band.

Comment: Ok so would the IRFP90N20D be good for say 160m or 80m above am broadcast  and if I add supply voltage say from 24vdc to 50vdc I'm not going to see much in power out put I would like to make one for a mobile application I would use a 2sc2879 but they're getting so expensive  and ldmos is the same and seem to run at Round 60vdc

Comment: @DavidStout Using 2SC2879 in this circuit would limit the supply to 22V because it is rated for Uce = 45V only.

Comment: Well it's working took more tinkering but at 25 vdc it's putting out 450w pep with 25  watts drive so I'm going to move on too a x4 mosfets version and to come up with power combiner to combine the 4 MOSFETs outputs thanks for the information

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be looking at this table in the [IRFP260N datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFP260N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535628a2ef1fe4):

[image]

Specifically the parameter "Drain-to-Source Breakdown Voltage."

What that line means is that the transistor will not blow up if you do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkrTGH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the gate is connected to the source - the MOSFET itself is not conducting current (except for the leakage current.)

All that means is that when there is no current flowing, you are allowed a maximum of 200V between the drain and source.

The problem that you have is the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzdQ2p.png)</sup>

R1 and R2 are the two halves of the 5k potentiometer in your circuit.

The transistor is conducting.  The voltage across the drain and source depend on the gate voltage, the transconductance value of the transistor, and the current your power supply really delivers.

Both of your transistors will be biased so that they are both conducting all the time.

What's killing your transistors is the current and the heat generated by that current in the transistors.

The datasheet mentions that the transistor is capable of dissipating 300 watts of power.  It also has a "safe operating area" diagram that shows you how long it can withstand various combinations of voltage (across drain and source) and current (through the drain.)

Safe operating area:

[image]

The dotted lines give the time limit when operated at the voltages and currents shown on the outer edges.

Note that the longest time is in milliseconds, and corresponds to around 400 watts.

To reach the limits given in the chart, you'll need to mount your transistors on a (probably rather large) heatsink.

---

I can't help you design your amplifier.  I don't know enough about the subject.

Comment: I posted a schematic

Comment: @DavidStout: I saw your schematic before I posted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

- shootthru currents are two failed components that are caused by lack of deadtime.  So delays are íntroduced in the design that are not definedin your problem

The other design parameter is flyback voltage